Using std::string and int inside the union
Is it correct to use std::string (or other non trivial types) with int (or other trivial and non trivial types) inside the same union?
I am already implemented it like this:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Foo
{
    enum Type {data_string, data_int};
    int m_type;
    
    Foo(Type t) : m_type(t)
    {
        if (t == Type::data_string) {
            new (&s) std::string();
        }
    }

    ~Foo()  
    {
        if (m_type == Type::data_string) {
            s.~basic_string();
        }
    }
    
    union
    {
        int n;
        std::string s;
    };
};

int main()
{
    Foo f1(Foo::Type::data_string);
    f1.s = "hello ";
    std::cout << f1.s;
    
    Foo f2(Foo::Type::data_int);
    f2.n = 100;
    std::cout << f2.n;
} 

and it works pretty good. But i am not sure about this code. Is it correct code from the C++ standard perspective?

You should use std::variant which is the proper generic sum-type for C++ (especially with non-trivial types).

@wohlstad thank you for suggestion, but anyway... i want know is it OK to use this code in C++ or there some undefined behavior exists?

Your code is clunky, but correct. Union is initialized and deinitlized in proper way. UB would be in case when you initialize union to one thing and use/deinitilize this as the other thing.

That's the primary implementation of std::variant. Why do you want to reinvent the wheel?  You are going to experience tedious failures into so many pitfalls regarding lifetime issues. Wrap variant in your class and provide a /*value_type*/* get<Type>(Foo&) accessor.

It looks fine, but you might also need copy/move constructors and copy/move assignment operators to make this type usable in practice ("rule of five"), e.g. in std::vector<Foo>. Using std::variant simplifies that task.

You should not use a union with non trivial types.
In the past a union did not deal with proper construction and destruction of C++ objects in it. In C++11 it was addressed to some extent by requiring you to supply a proper constructor and destructor but you still had to keep track of the current type held in it.
You took care of it manually in your code, which is technically correct, but very much error prone. You can easily get into UB land if you construct or destruct the wrong type in the union.
In general in C++ is it advised to use std::variant for a generic sum-type / discriminated union (requires #include <variant>).
From the documentation:

The class template std::variant represents a type-safe union.

(emphasys is mine)
std::variant safely takes care of construction, destruction and assignment (copy or move) of the objects in it.
So instead of your union I recommend to use something like:
std::variant<int, std::string> m_value;

This way your Foo constructor and destructor can be defaulted. The variant will take care of proper construction and destruction of the std::string (or any other non-trivial type in it).

"A union is not meant to deal with proper construction and detruction of C++ objects in it." - that was true in the old days, but was addressed in C++11. But yes, std::variant is preferred now

@wohlstad I was under the impression that the "marketing's" main selling point was type-safety. But cppref does mention "All types must meet the Destructible requirements (in particular, array types and non-object types are not allowed).", but unions do have a "since C++11" marker related to constructors and destructors. I think that's what Remy meant.

@TheNomad - fixed the typo - thanks.

@RemyLebeau if I understand correctly since C++11 you are required to supply constructor and destructor for the union holding non-trivial types, but you still have to keep track of the current type "manually" (unlike with a std::variant). Updated my answer.
